# terminating the whole application after facing error in an specific activity

Tags: java, android

i have an application which has couple of activities and what's happening is :

When an error occurs in one of these activities and i face the " unfortunately X application has stopped working " error, only that one activity stops working and it automatically jumps to another activity and keeps running the app with the errors on the background,

what i'm looking for is :

is there any way to add any sort of code to the manifest section that terminate the whole application in case of facing error in an specific activity or even adding an additional code to the activities which has high risk of facing errors ?

my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.dpDemo.dpDemo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/titl"
    android:label="FINDER III"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstLoad"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".welcome" />
    <activity android:name=".BluetoothConnectionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DeviceList" />
    <activity android:name=".AutoAndManual" />
    <activity android:name=".MetalList" />
    <activity android:name=".FreQuencyManual" />
    <activity android:name=".CommunicationAuto" />
    <activity android:name=".CommunicationAuto2" />
    <activity android:name=".CommunicationAuto3" />
    <activity android:name=".CommunicationAuto4" />
    <activity android:name=".LoadingNewOne" />
    <activity android:name=".FinalAutoResult" />
    <activity android:name=".Security" />
    <activity android:name=".LoadingNewTwo" />
    <activity android:name=".LoadingNewThree" />
    <activity android:name=".LoadingNewFour" />
    <activity android:name=".AutoSelection" />
    <activity android:name=".powerLowResult" />
    <activity android:name=".powerMediumResult" />
    <activity android:name=".powerHighResult" />
    <activity android:name=".ClassLow" />
    <activity android:name=".ClassMedium" />
    <activity android:name=".ClassHigh" />
    <activity android:name=".ErrorPowerFinal" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ExitActivity"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <activity android:name=".Filters" />
    <activity android:name=".ft1" />
    <activity android:name=".filterFinalResultWorking" />
    <activity android:name=".PowerDirectionX"></activity>
</application>
```

One of the activities as example:

```
public class Filters extends AppCompatActivity {


Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
Button btn4;
Button btn5;
Button btn6;
Button returnMenu;


Handler h;

private OutputStream outStream = null;
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

private static String address = "20:16:06:28:17:83";



final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;        // Status  for Handler
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private Filters.ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;







@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}












@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filters);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn3);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn4);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn5);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterBtn6);
    returnMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnChris);









    Handler mouse = new Handler();
    mouse.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            btn2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
            btn3.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1500);
            btn4.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
            btn5.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2500);
            btn6.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000);
            returnMenu.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1500);


        }
    },500);





    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                  
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                         
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);            
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                        sbprint.getBytes().toString();


                    }

                    break;
            }
        };
    };






    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();      
    checkBTState();






    returnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {





            AlertDialog.Builder builderjt = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderjt.setTitle(" Confirmation ");
            builderjt.setMessage(" Return to Main menu?");


            builderjt.setPositiveButton(" Yes ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    mConnectedThread.write("back");
                    returnMenu.setEnabled(false);
                    btn1.setEnabled(false);
                    btn2.setEnabled(false);
                    btn3.setEnabled(false);
                    btn4.setEnabled(false);
                    btn5.setEnabled(false);
                    btn6.setEnabled(false);



                    Handler handlerNew2 = new Handler();
                    handlerNew2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Intent returnToFreK = new Intent(Filters.this,AutoAndManual.class);
                            startActivity(returnToFreK);

                        }
                    },2000);







                }
            });

            builderjt.setNegativeButton(" No ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });



            AlertDialog dialog = builderjt.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });









    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder builderx = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderx.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builderx.setMessage(" Filter 1 selected, Are you sure?");

            builderx.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProx = new Intent(Filters.this,ft1.class);
                    startActivity(intentProx);
                    finish();




                }
            });


            builderx.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogx = builderx.create();
            dialogx.show();










        }
    });



    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder builderg = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderg.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builderg.setMessage(" Filter 2 selected, Are you sure?");

            builderg.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProh = new Intent(Filters.this,ft2.class);
                    startActivity(intentProh);
                    finish();




                }
            });


            builderg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogg = builderg.create();
            dialogg.show();










        }
    });



    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder builderq = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderq.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builderq.setMessage(" Filter 3 selected, Are you sure?");

            builderq.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProq = new Intent(Filters.this,ft3.class);
                    startActivity(intentProq);




                }
            });


            builderq.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogq = builderq.create();
            dialogq.show();










        }
    });




    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder builderu = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderu.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builderu.setMessage(" Filter 4 selected, Are you sure?");

            builderu.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProu = new Intent(Filters.this,ft4.class);
                    startActivity(intentProu);




                }
            });


            builderu.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogu = builderu.create();
            dialogu.show();










        }
    });




    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder buildero = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            buildero.setTitle("Confirmation");
            buildero.setMessage(" Filter 5 selected, Are you sure?");

            buildero.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProo = new Intent(Filters.this,ft5.class);
                    startActivity(intentProo);




                }
            });


            buildero.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogo = buildero.create();
            dialogo.show();










        }
    });




    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            AlertDialog.Builder builderk = new AlertDialog.Builder(Filters.this);
            builderk.setTitle("Confirmation");
            builderk.setMessage(" Filter 6 selected, Are you sure?");

            builderk.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    Intent intentProk = new Intent(Filters.this,ft6.class);
                    startActivity(intentProk);




                }
            });


            builderk.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.cancel();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialogk = builderk.create();
            dialogk.show();










        }
    });


}






private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();




    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);




    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }



    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


    try {
        btSocket.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {

        }
    }




    mConnectedThread = new Filters.ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();



    try     {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {

    }
}

private void checkBTState() {


    if(btAdapter==null) {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Bluetooth is not supported. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {




        } else {


            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);


        }
    }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;


        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  
        int bytes;


        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);     
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void write(String message) {




        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {


            mConnectedThread.write("back");


        }
    }}}
```

Comment: catch that error and call `System.exit(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code that might help you :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  public void onCreate ()
  {
    // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
      {
        handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
      }
    });
  }

  public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
  {
    //Write your code here to manage
    System.exit(1); // kill off the crashed app
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Manifest do not provide any utility to do so. 
What you must do is to wrap all the relevant functions of your android code in try and catch block. You can then catch any exceptions for which you want to close the app and in the catch section use this code:

```
try{
 // code
 }catch(Exceptions e){
 finishAffinity();
 System.exit(0);
 }
```

finishAffinity() is a safe way to close the app, though it may wait for some time.
System.exit(0) immediately closes the application, though it may have some side effects of abrupt closing of application.